# Does the .Net Framework implementation of Linq optimize Skip for indexable types?

Tags: linq, performance, indexing, linq-to-objects

Here's an example:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(string arg in args.Skip(77))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Assuming enough `args`, does this call `MoveNext` 77 times inside `Skip`?  Or does `Skip` jump straight to the appropriate index?

Comment: 78 command-line arguments later, only to get a single value printed out on screen.  I LOVE IT. ;)

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/26/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-40-optimization.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embarrassingly, I was wrong.

## No.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Skip<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source"); 
    return SkipIterator<TSource>(source, count); 
}

static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count) {
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        while (count > 0 && e.MoveNext()) count--;
        if (count <= 0) { 
            while (e.MoveNext()) yield return e.Current;
        } 
    } 
}
```

Jon Skeet [explains](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/26/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-40-optimization.aspx) why it can't do that.

Comment: +1 for the code and the link.  I found [the article where he implemented the optimization](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/02/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-23-take-skip-takewhile-skipwhile.aspx), but I couldn't find a link to the article where he explained why he couldn't do the optimization ("on a postcard").